# Есть компонент с вводом пароля, я их размещаю несколько штук в родителе, мне нужно привязать v-model на эти дочерние компоненты

Tags: javascript, vue.js

есть такой дочерний компонент:

```js
import IconSprite from '@/components/interface/IconSprite.vue'

export default {
    components: { IconSprite },
    props: {
        placeholder: {
            type: String,
        },
    },
    data() {
        return {
            password: '',
            showPassword: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        togglePasswordVisibility() {
            this.showPassword = !this.showPassword
        },
    },
}
```

```html
<div class="password">
    <input
        class="noBorder"
        v-model="password"
        :placeholder="placeholder"
        :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
    />
</div>
```

и такой родитель:

```js
import IconSprite from '@/components/interface/IconSprite.vue'
import passwordInput from '@/components/pages/SettingPage/settingActions/interface/password-input.vue'
import TheButton from '@/components/interface/TheButton.vue'

export default {
    components: { TheButton, IconSprite, passwordInput },
    props: {},
    data() {
        return {
            password: '',
            showPassword: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {},
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="settinActiontitle heading_2">Заполните данные</h1>
        <div class="changePassword">
            <password-input class="password-now" placeholder="Текущий пароль" />
            <div class="password-info">
                <IconSprite name="icon-info" class-name="icon-info" />
                <div>
                    <p class="footnote_l">Минимальная длина пароля – 8 символов.</p>
                    <p class="footnote_l">
                        Не используйте пароли от других сайтов или варианты
                    </p>
                    <p class="footnote_l">которые злоумышленники смогут легко подобрать.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <password-input class="password-new" placeholder="Новый пароль" />
            <password-input class="password-again" placeholder="Повторите новый пароль" />
            <TheButton btn-text="Сохранить" theme-use="yellow-btn" class="saveBtn" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Как мне добавить v-model в родителе?